# How to have tabs on top, bottom and both sides (horizontal and vertical)

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm trying to use jQuery tabs (see [tabs](http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#default)) and create a box with tabs all around it, top, bottom and both sides. I tried to play with jQuery tabs for about 3 hours and I can't figure out.

[Here](http://postimg.org/image/dwtgqijvh/) is the tabbed box I'm trying to create.

Comment: You are probably looking at "4" tab groups - top, left, right, bottom...

Comment: Can you show an example of how far you've got with this?

Comment: here is what i got so far, http://jsfiddle.net/bpJUv/220/  however i cant get it nested with 4 sides tabs to the bottom and the right side??

Answer (score 0):

Why use tabs, why not have them in a list, style the ul and li elements how you want, like in the image and just have a universal toggle to show content, using matching id's for the li's and content. for example:

```
<ul class="food_thumbs">
<li data-food="apple">apple image</li>
<li data-food="orange">orange image</li>
<li data-food="pear">pear image</li>
</ul>

<ul class="food_content">
<li data-food="apple">apple text</li>
<li data-food="orange">orange text</li>
<li data-food="pear">pear text</li>
</ul>
```

or something to that effect